# Call a function when window is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, window-resize

How can I call for this(or any) JS function to be run again whenever the Browser window is resized?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function setEqualHeight(e) {
     var t = 0;
     e.each(function () {
         currentHeight = $(this).height();
         if (currentHeight > t) {
             t = currentHeight
         }
     });
     e.height(t)
 }
 $(document).ready(function () {
     setEqualHeight($(".border"))
 })
</script>
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use the window `onresize` event:

```
window.onresize = setEqualHeight;
```

Answer (score 26):

You can subscribe to the `window.onresize` event ([See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onresize))

```
window.onresize = setEqualHeight;
```

or

```
window.addEventListener('resize', setEqualHeight);
```

Answer (score 21):

This piece of code will add a timer which calls the resize function after 200 milliseconds after the window has been resized. This will reduce the calls of the method.

```js
var globalResizeTimer = null;

$(window).resize(function() {
    if(globalResizeTimer != null) window.clearTimeout(globalResizeTimer);
    globalResizeTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
        setEqualHeight();
    }, 200);
});
```

Comment: big up for reducing calls of the method

Answer (score 14):

You use jquery, so bind it using the [`.resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) method.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    setEqualHeight( $('#border') );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has recently added support for the [ResizeObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) which allows you to bind a callback to any specific element (especially useful if you want to target particular elements which may be resized even if the whole page isn't); however, you can also use it to target the whole document by passing in the root element.

```
const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries, observer) => {
  // if necessary, you can do something with the entries which fired the event, 
  // or the observer itself (for example stop observing an element)
  setEqualHeight();
});

//to attach to the whole document
resizeObserver.observe(document.documentElement);

//to attach to specific target element(s)
resizeObserver.observe(document.querySelector(".container"));
```