# detect when div width is change using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new in javascript and I want to perform some action when the div with is changed

in jquery, I use this code

```
var width = $(window).width();
$(window).resize(function(){
   if($(this).width() != width){
      width = $(this).width();
       console.log(width);
   }
});
```

but I want to do it using javascript
help me please...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205609/call-a-function-when-window-is-resized

Comment: Why would you not want to do this with jQuery?

Comment: actually, I don't want to use jquery on my whole site because I have not included jquery on my site it take 91 kb and I am, try reduce the size of my website

Comment: Use ResizeObserver: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39312522/47528

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use on-resize-event like this:

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
    var width = body.offsetWidth;
    
    if (window.addEventListener) {  // all browsers except IE before version 9
      window.addEventListener ("resize", onResizeEvent, true);
    } else {
      if (window.attachEvent) {   // IE before version 9
        window.attachEvent("onresize", onResizeEvent);
      }
    }
    
    function onResizeEvent() {
      bodyElement = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
      newWidth = bodyElement.offsetWidth;
      if(newWidth != width){
        width = newWidth;
        console.log(width);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the onresize event

```
window.onresize = functionName
```

Answer (score 0):

In Internet Explorer you can use "onresize", to trigger a JavaScript function whenever size of an element(div) or body is changed.

But "onresize" does not work the same way in other browsers. Mozilla Firefox will trigger the function only when body is resized not a div.

```
<body onresize="myFunction()">
```

will work in every browser

```
<div onresize="myFunction()">
```

Will work only in IE