# Dynamically set CSS border-bottom-left-radius based on sibling's width

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I'm looking for a way to achieve what twitter does in their messenger regarding the `border-radius`. To make it simpler to explain I'll first add some photos:

Image with `border-bottom-left-radius` set:

[image]

Image **without** `border-bottom-left-radius`:

[image]

Any idea on how twitter dynamically sets the `border-radius` (in this case `border-bottom-left-radius`) based on the width of the text message attached to it?

```css
.image {
    border-radius: 1.25rem 1.25rem 0 1.25rem;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 70%;
}

.text {
    border-radius: 0 0 0 1.25rem;
    float: right;
    background-color: rgb(230, 236, 240);
    height: 40px;
    max-width: 70%;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.divider {
    display:block; 
    margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<img class="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a3/Miscanti_Lagoon_near_San_Pedro_de_Atacama_Chile_Luca_Galuzzi_2006.jpg/512px-Miscanti_Lagoon_near_San_Pedro_de_Atacama_Chile_Luca_Galuzzi_2006.jpg" />

<div class="text">
    <span>This is the text</span>
</div>

<div class="divider"></div>

<img class="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a3/Miscanti_Lagoon_near_San_Pedro_de_Atacama_Chile_Luca_Galuzzi_2006.jpg/512px-Miscanti_Lagoon_near_San_Pedro_de_Atacama_Chile_Luca_Galuzzi_2006.jpg" />

<div class="text">
    <span>This is just a relatively longer text for the sake of demonstrating this example!!</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So based on your explication.

I added a `border-radius` for your class `img` as followed:

```
border-radius: 1.25rem 1.25rem 0 0;
```

Then I added a padding to your text class to make it nicer and finaly. replace your `span` to set you `p` element as followed:

```
.text p{
  margin: 0 7px;
}
```

This way text satys away from the `border-radius`.

You need to add to your class `.text { width: fit-content}`

So we finaly added js to adjust `border-bottom-left-radius` when the text width is equal to img width. And we create the class to add in case widths are equal:

```
.border-bottom-left-radius{
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

As mentionned by hatef in comment. It was dynamic for reload window but not resizing. To do so I adapted code from existing code in this answer: [detect when div width is change using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39845560/detect-when-div-width-is-change-using-javascript)

By adding this js that will detect the change of body element if it would be resized:

```js
displayWindowSize();
window.addEventListener("resize", displayWindowSize);

function displayWindowSize(){
    const imgEl = document.getElementById('img');
    const textEl = document.getElementById('text');

  if(imgEl.offsetWidth <= textEl.offsetWidth){
      imgEl.classList.add("custom-radius");
  }

  if(imgEl.offsetWidth > textEl.offsetWidth){
    imgEl.classList.remove("custom-radius");
  }
}
```

```css
.image {
    border-radius: 1.25rem 1.25rem 0 1.25rem;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 70%;
}

.text{
    float: right;
    background-color: rgb(230, 236, 240);
    border-radius: 0 0 0 1.25rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    width:fit-content;
    max-width: 70%;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

.text span{
  display:block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.custom-radius {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<img id="img" class="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a3/Miscanti_Lagoon_near_San_Pedro_de_Atacama_Chile_Luca_Galuzzi_2006.jpg/512px-Miscanti_Lagoon_near_San_Pedro_de_Atacama_Chile_Luca_Galuzzi_2006.jpg" />

<div id="text" class="text">
    <span>This is the text This is a text this is a text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to answer my question. However, if you look at the first photo I posted above, the width of the text is dynamic and it changes based on the content. The max-width is matching with the content and that only happens for relatively long texts.

Comment: @Mr.Robot I actualy fixed this by replacing your span element by p element as it is display block default for p and inline for span. If you check the example with short text, it works fine

Comment: Ah sorry i meant _left_ not _right_! Edited my question :)

Comment: I updated my snippet, I guess what you are searching for is: `width:fit-content;` Added in `.text` class

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I updated my question again. This works fine but the thing is I would like to remove the `border-bottom-left-radius` on the `img` when the text reaches the max-wdith (please look at the second picture in my question).

Comment: oh okay, I think only way to make it will be to use js or jquery, would it be fine for you ?

Comment: I don't really mind JavaScript or CSS. I just can't find a way for this, I feel like it's simple but I can't think of a good solution. :S

Comment: @Mr.Robot Here you go. I made an easy case with getElementById If now you want to use classe, you will need to same"if" but in loop. as getElementsByClass will return an array

Comment: @MaxiGui this only works on page reload i.e. it wouldn't adjust dynamically on window resize, but it should give them an idea. Plus, I wouldn't use `border-bottom-left-radius` as a class name.

Comment: @hatef you are right about resizing window so I updated my answer with code taken from an existing subject to make it clear (even though I don't really get the goal to do so).  For the classname, it is really for the example here to be clear. But if you have any other suggestion for my future answer, I would be happy to know.

Comment: Great, I edited your code to make it slightly simpler to read. I hope you don't mind! :)